# Angular mousedown and mouseup issue

Tags: angularjs, mouseevent, mousedown, mouseup

I'm trying to track an event on both mouseup and down, using AngularJS. Every mouse (and key-event), is working, except mousedown. I tried them all with the function as shown below, and only mousedown fails. Besides, the problem seems to occurs over the entire website.

```
<div id="svgholder" ng-controller="FloorPlanController as floorplanCtrl" ng-mouseup="floorplanCtrl.click($event)" ng-mousedown="floorplanCtrl.click($event)">
```

**I already found several issues where plugins like batarang seems to cause this problem, but even without plugins this seems to occur**

This problem already consumed to much time, so i really hope someone has the solution to this!

*info: AngularJS 1.5.5 with Chrome, safari and firefox*

**UPDATE: even with pure jquery mousedown is not registered**

**UPDATE: controller code**

The function that is triggerd bij both mousedown and up, where only mouse up seems to be working.

```
o.click = function($event){

        console.log($event);

        if (angular.element($event.target)[0].nodeName !== "path" && angular.element($event.target)[0].nodeName === "rect") {
            ContentService.setActiveSpaces([]);
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide controller code and detailed html.

Comment: Can you provide a demo of your issue ?

Comment: @KhaledBentoumi i can't, since it is a enormous webplatform, and the issue happens allover the platform. It is impossible to post the entire code + html